# How should i implement modman in my project?

Tags: magento-1.9, modman

I have a Magento project directory, And now we want to implement Modman with the project, so where should I start the Modman? and where to put the .modman folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should check:

**How to Use Modman:**

1. http://andykdocs.de/development/Magento/2013-03-15+Deploying+Magento+Modules+with+modman
2. https://github.com/colinmollenhour/modman/wiki/Tutorial